# Vector different length after unlist

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a list to a vector so I can attach it to a dataframe but it's throwing an error.  After unlisting the list, it became shorter and I'm not sure why.

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
> mongo_jr$last_state <- unlist(last_state)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "last_state", value = c("created",  : 
  replacement has 203819 rows, data has 203823

> str(last_state)
List of 203823

x <- unlist(last_state)

> str(x)
 chr [1:203819] "created" "created" "created" "created" "created" "created" "created" "created" ...
```

Comment: Are any of the vectors in `last_state` empty? Run `table(sapply(last_state,length))` and see if you have any 0 length vectors mixed in there.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out some of the values were null

```
transition_duration[sapply(last_state, is.null)] <- NA
mongo_jr$last_state <- unlist(last_state)
```

worked.